# Get POST data on Webpage from Android-App?

Tags: php, android, request, http-post, send

I am trying to output POST-data that I send from an android phone, however I cannot manage to get any output in my PHP file.
This is my php code:

```
<?php
  echo "POSTed data: '".$_POST['mydata']."'<br>";
  var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

this is my android code (which seems to work fine)

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myurl.php");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mydata", "12345"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringData", "SomeData"));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

// Execute HTTP Post Request  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
toSendET.setText(responseText);
```

Is it even possible to send POST data to an static PHP script via phone?

Comment: where do you create `httppost` - can you please include the code ? and where do you expect to see the output of the PHP ?

Comment: What does your responseText say?

Comment: @jsaye my response gives me back HTML-Code with POST requests filled in, e.g. " POSTed data: '12345' " etc

Comment: @ManseUK I create the httppost right above "
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.php");" where myurl is the url to my php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have got is working fine - but when you echo something in PHP its echo'd back to the caller - ie the browser in this case.

If you check the value of `response` in the code on Android is will be `POSTed data: '12344'<br>`

See the [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function in PHP for logging to a file

Comment: So the POST Data can only be echoed back to the sender (in this case the phone)? So I would have to dump the POST data into a mysql database for example and then display that data via another PHP to the user? Thanks I think I get it.

Comment: you could use the error_log() function (in my answer) or do what ever you need to do with the POST data and send a valid response - either HTML / Plain Text / JSON or XML - whatever is expected